# Javascript to hide/unhide viewbag items based on textbox keyup

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I am wanting my users to enter their login name into a textbox field and have a list of radio buttons appear below that contain patient sets associated with their username. However I can only seem to get the first item in my Viewbag to work. Below is the js I am using.

```
<script>

        var check = function () {          

                 if (document.getElementById('Username').value ==    
                     document.getElementById('projects').getAttribute("name")) 
                 {    
                         var userName = document.getElementById('Username').value;    
                         document.getElementsByName(userName)[0].style.display = 'table-row';    
                 } 
                 else 
                 {
                     document.getElementById('projects').style.display = 'none';    
                 }    
         }    
        </script>
```

Here is the body:

```
<div class="row">    
    <div class="col-md-8">    
        <form asp-action="SubmitAttempt" method="post">    
            <div class="form-group">    
                <label name="Username" class="control-label">Enter Username</label>    
                <input name="Username" id="Username" class="form-control" required onkeyup="check();"/>    
            </div>    
           <div class="form-group">    
                <label name="Email" class="control-label">Enter Email Address</label>    
                <input name="Email" class="form-control" required />    
            </div>    
            <table border="1" style="margin: 5px">    
                @if (ViewBag.Subs != null)    
                {    
                    foreach (var subs in ViewBag.Subs)    
                    {    
                    <tr id="projects" name="@subs.Username" style="display:none" value="@subs.Username">    
                        <td><input type="radio" value="@subs.PatientName" name="PatientName" class="form-control"/></td>    
                        <td>@subs.ProjectName</td>    
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>    
                        <td>@subs.PatientSet</td>    
                    </tr>    
                    }    
                }    
            </table>    
            <div>    
                <p>Click Submit</p>    
            </div>    
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />    
        </form>    
    </div>    
</div>
```

Should I use a loop in my js to check each tr and compare with the text input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I use a loop in my js to check each tr and compare with the text input?

Yes, you need to use loop to compare one by one.

Besides, there are some mistakes in your codes, I suggest not to use Id selector, since there are many trs with the same id, it will always select the first one when you use Id selector.

I made some changes, you can refer to the below codes:

```
<table border="1" style="margin: 5px">
    @if (ViewBag.Subs != null)
    {
        foreach (var subs in ViewBag.Subs)
        {
            <tr id="projects" name="subsName" style="display:none" value="@subs.UserName">
                <td><input type="radio" value="@subs.PatientName" name="PatientName" class="form-control" /></td>
                <td>@subs.ProjectName</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>@subs.PatientSet</td>
            </tr>

        }
    }
</table>


<script>

    var check = function () {
        var userName = document.getElementById('Username').value;
        var trs = document.getElementsByName('subsName');
        for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
            if (userName == trs[i].getAttribute("value")) {
                trs[i].style.display = 'table-row';
            }
            else {
                trs[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```